# Lambda use with Scapy

Tags: python, lambda, network-programming, scapy

I'm new to Python and have come across the use of lambda functions when utilising an ICMP ping scan with Scapy. I've read a few tutorials but I'm struggling to get my head around the concept to utilise my code properly.

I'm trying to figure out how exactly the lambda arguments reference the output that is given by Scapy; Mainly the functionality of 's' and 'r' and how they can directly pull out data from the IP field using '%IP.src%' ?

```
def icmp_ping(target_ip):
"Function for a classic ICMP Ping sweep."
    ans,unans=sr(IP(dst=target_ip)/ICMP(), timeout=3)
    ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("%IP.src% is alive") )
    ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("%IP.ttl% is the TTL value") )
    print(ans)
```

Which gives the output:

```
Received 3 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 10 packets
192.168.0.100 is alive
64 is the TTL value
[(<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp dst=192.168.0.100 |<ICMP  |>>, <IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=28 id=30394 flags= frag=0L ttl=64 proto=icmp chksum=0x820d src=192.168.0.100 dst=192.168.0.101 options=[] |<ICMP  type=echo-reply code=0 chksum=0xffff id=0x0 seq=0x0 |<Padding  load='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' |>>>)]
```

Hope the question makes sense!

Comment: Seems like I've managed to figure it out somewhat. The lambda functionality is equivilent to that of `code` for s,r in ans: `code` where s = send and r= receive. Then use sprintf to pull out the required data.

Answer (score 0):

ans has tuple which contains send and receive packets. Lambda takes this tuple. You are reaching out IP header of received packet and writing source address. In python3 you must write as following

```
 ans.summary(lambda p: p[1].sprintf("%IP.src% is alive"))
```

in python 3 parameters come as tuple and you have to reach receive packet by its index